OpenOCD - Not Enough Working Area Available (Cortex M0+, LPC8xx, CMSIS-DAP)
First time using OpenOCD and trying to write an image to an LPC824 chip. I can connect to the chip and probe it using the configs supplied with OpenOCD.
When I try to write the image I get the error "no working area specified, can't write LPC2000 internal flash".
Whilst the error seems clear, I have been unable to find any information on how I go about setting the working area to solve this issue. Could someone point me in the right direction please?
Command an output from the OpenOCD process:
openocd -d2 -s /openocd/scripts -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/lpc8xx.cfg
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Atomic commands supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.10
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Serial# = 1503603D
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 0 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 10 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x0bc11477
Info : [lpc8xx.cpu] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [lpc8xx.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for lpc8xx.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'telnet' connection on tcp/4444

Output from telnet session in another window showing successful probes and then the working area issue:
> reset halt
[lpc8xx.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x1fff0008 msp: 0x10000ffc
> flash probe 0
flash 'lpc2000' found at 0x00000000

> flash banks
#0 : lpc8xx.flash (lpc2000) at 0x00000000, size 0x00008000, buswidth 0, chipwidth 0

> flash list
{name lpc8xx.flash driver lpc2000 base 0 size 32768 bus_width 0 chip_width 0 target lpc8xx.cpu}
> flash write_image erase blinky_green.hex
not enough working area available(requested 1024)
no working area specified, can't write LPC2000 internal flash
error writing to flash at address 0x00000000 at offset 0x00000000
auto erase enabled

